# Wireshark display filter: host to host

Tags: wireshark

I need to Write a Wireshark display filter to meet the following requirements.

**All traffic from host 192.168.12.44 to host 192.168.12.1**

I  believe it is just

```
ip.src_host =  192.168.12.44 && ip.dst_host 192.168.12.1
```

or

```
ip.src== 192.168.12.44 && ip.dst==192.168.12.1
```

I'm just not sure which syntax is correct. Can anyone offer any tips/advice? I tried this on two different IPs that i can actually test yet they seem to offer different results, so I'm not sure which one I need.

Answer (score 1):

ip.src & ip.dst are for IP adresses while ip.src_host & ip.dst_host are for their DNS names. Suppose an IP with the address **192.168.1.1** has a corresponding DNS name of **mydns.mysite.com**. Assuming you have enabled **Resolve Network Address** under View --> Name Resolution, then ip.src_host will filter **mydns.mysite.com** while when not enabled ip.src will filter **192.168.1.1**
Please refer to this [link](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/i/ip.html) for more information.